# Programatically specify Google Analytics Reporting API v4 query results

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

How does one query specific pages? I only need to grab the data from specific pages.

Example: domain.com/thisPage, domain.com/anotherPage, etc..

```
ReportRequest reportRequestLandingPath = new ReportRequest
{
    ViewId = GoogleAnalyticsIds,
    DateRanges = new List<DateRange>() { dateRange },
    Dimensions = new List<Dimension>() { landingPagePath },
    Metrics = new List<Metric>() { avgSessionDuration, sessions, pageviewsPerSession }
};
```

I'm trying to get results that look [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNJ9h.png)  so I can add them to a google chart I'm building.

My problem is that I get back all 78 results for each page I have on my domain. I only need to get avgSessionDuration, sessions, pageviewsPerSession from 5-6 specific pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a filter to your request just add which ever pages that you want to see data for and only the data for those pages will be returned.

```
var metrics = new List<Metric>();
metrics.Add(new Metric { Expression = "ga:avgSessionDuration", Alias = "Avg. Session Duration" });
metrics.Add(new Metric { Expression = "ga:sessions", Alias = "Sessions" });
metrics.Add(new Metric { Expression = "ga:pageviewsPerSession", Alias = "Pageviews Per Session" });

var dimensions = new List<Dimension>();
dimensions.Add(new Dimension { Name = "ga:landingPagePath" });

var filterClause = new DimensionFilterClause();

var filter = new DimensionFilter
         {
         DimensionName = "ga:landingPagePath",
         Operator__ = "PARTIAL",
         Expressions = new List<string> { "accessing-google-calendar-with-php-oauth2" }
        };
filterClause.Filters = new List<DimensionFilter> { filter };
ReportRequest reportRequest = new ReportRequest
            {
                ViewId = "78110423",
                DateRanges = new List<DateRange>() { new DateRange() { StartDate = "3daysago", EndDate = "today" } },
                Dimensions = dimensions,
                Metrics = metrics,
                DimensionFilterClauses = new List<DimensionFilterClause> { filterClause }
            };

List<ReportRequest> requests = new List<ReportRequest>();
requests.Add(reportRequest);

// Create the GetReportsRequest object.
GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest() { ReportRequests = requests };
```

I recommend using [Query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) for testing your filters it can be tricky to get them to work.

Comment: I have a list of strings in the Expressions variable. But the getReport only returns the value for the 0th list item and none of the other list item results.

Comment: @NucleusDev i think you should open a new question.